# Consider equilateral triangle ABC and points D and E such that $BD = \frac{BC} 3$. If DF is perepndicular on AD, F belongs to AC, prove that EF = AD.

Tags: geometry, triangles, median

Consider equilateral triangle ABC and points D and E such that $BD = \frac{BC} 3$, DE belongs to (BC), and E is the midpoint of (AD). If DF is perepndicular on AD, F belongs to AC, prove that EF = AD.

**my ideas**

*MY DRAWING*

[image]

Okey so all i could thought of is the formula of the median. I thought we can apply it in the triangle AFD with the median FE. Another thing i thought of it that $BD = \frac{BC} 3$, that knida reminds me of the propriety of the G center.

Comment: I request you to provide the source of this question. Thanks (edit it into the question).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I can't really, because the question is in my language. This is the direct translate of it...im sorry

Comment: I see, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: sorry for the lack of illustrations, feel free to add one or give suggestions on how to add them.

My proof uses the Pythagorean theorem **a lot**, not the prettiest proof ever :)

So, if the sides of $\triangle ABC$ are of length $2x$, we can find $AD=\sqrt{(\sqrt3\cdot x)^2+\left(\frac13x\right)^2}=\frac23\sqrt7\cdot x$ using the Pythagorean theorem. Also note the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\sqrt3\cdot x^2$.

*(If you wonder where $\sqrt3\cdot x$ and $\frac13x$ came from, draw $P$ as the midpoint of $BC$ and we can see that $\triangle ADP$ is a right triangle)*

Now, I created a point $G$ in $AD$ so that $CG\parallel FD$.
As the area of $\triangle ACD$ is $\frac23\sqrt3\cdot x^2$, we can find that $CG=\frac{\frac43\sqrt3\cdot x^2}{AD}=\frac27\sqrt{21}\cdot x$.

Again, using the Pythagorean theorem, we can find that $AG=\sqrt{(2x)^2-\left(\frac27\sqrt{21}\cdot x\right)^2}=\frac47\sqrt7\cdot x$.

Notice that $\triangle ACG\sim\triangle AFD$, which means $\frac{CG}{FD}=\frac{AG}{AD}$. So:

$\frac{\frac27\sqrt{21}\cdot x}{FD}=\frac{\frac47\sqrt7\cdot x}{\frac23\sqrt7\cdot x}$

We can find that $FD=\frac13\sqrt{21}\cdot x$.

As we know $ED=\frac12AD=\frac13\sqrt7\cdot x$, using the Pythagorean theorem <s>(I promise this is the last time)</s> we can find that $EF=\sqrt{\left(\frac13\sqrt{21}\cdot x\right)^2+\left(\frac13\sqrt7\cdot x\right)^2}=\frac23\sqrt7\cdot x$

...which is the same as $AD!$ Definitely not the most elegant proof (considering all the Pythagorases), but that's what I came up with.

Comment: $AD=\sqrt{(\sqrt3\cdot x)^2+\left(\frac13x\right)^2}=\frac23\sqrt7\cdot x$ shouldn't be $AD=\sqrt{(\sqrt3\cdot x)^2-\left(\frac13x\right)^2}=\frac23\sqrt7\cdot x$

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? My answer has the first form, which is correct (I've rechecked just now to be sure, and $AD$ is the hypothenuse of $\triangle ADP$)

Comment: i don't think so. Isn't it the cateth. Can you make a drawing just so i can see more clearly what did you mean?

Comment: its okey now. I understood. Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart

Comment: Hey, no problem! It was fun solving this :)